# How to make a TfrxMemoview flow onto second page

Tags: fastreport

I have a report that has two dynamically sized TfrxMemoViews. They start out about 20 high and grow as needed.
Now I have a record that has more than enough data to cause the Memo to exceed the page height.
How can I the data flow into a MemoView on the next page?

I have created a demo app. Please take a look. Any suggestions?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gpbw9wuxgl19xh/ReportTest4.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
I put a Master and Detail. The master shows the recipe name.
The detail has everything else. If too much data, it flows to a new page.